# checking for letters in a string of ints

Tags: c++, string, function, int

```
bool isInt(string input) { //checks if string input is an int 
if (input[0] == '-') { //checks if negative number
    for (int a = 1; a < input.length(); a++) {
        if (isdigit(input[a])) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} 
for (int b = 0; b < input.length(); b++) {
    if (isdigit(input[b])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

So my code here is to check the string input the user enters and sees if its an integer. It works except cases where if the first character is either - or a number, but if thats followed by characters such as -23ab or -4b, my program won't catch that as an error as it isn't a valid number. I know the error is due to my return true/false statements, but I don't know of any method of how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: if you want to convert a string to an integer then `char* pStr = "-h4dfg";
 int a = atoi(pStr);
 cout << a;
` atoi() returns 0 if there's a letter which is leftmost of digits

Comment: std::strtol would be more useful, @Raindrop7 . It will tell you what character it stopped converting on and if that character was not a null, it stopped too soon. Not sure about the overflow case, though. I think it's stupid and keeps going after overflowing the integer but not 100% sure.

Comment: Your loops can never iterate through the entire string because they contains `if this { return } else { return }`.They decide what value to return, and take that action, after looking at just one character!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work at all!!

It only cares about the first character in the string because you `return` no matter the state of the character. You need to store a result in a variable and continue searching until the first failure.

Comment: ...or even without variable: Return on first error, else return after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning true as soon as you see 1 digit. You should return true only if you make it to the end of the string w/o an error. You can return false early but for this problem, you should only return true at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As others here said, you're only checking the first character and returning whether the first character is a digit or not....what you'll want to do instead is check if the character is a digit....if so then continue you on to the next digit. The only reason you'll return is if you either went through all the characters or if you found a non digit character.

```
for each character
   if character is a digit
      do nothing
   else
      return that it is false.
return true //you will only get to this statement if all characters are digits
```

This is what you have...

```
for each character 
   if character is a digit 
       return true
   else 
       return false
```

So its basically returning before it checks the rest of the characters

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying *too* hard. You're testing for both success and failure rather than just looking for a fail case.

The following code takes a position index of 0, if the string isn't empty, it checks for a leading '-' and increments the index position to 1 if it finds that.

Then it simply checks through the string for a non-numeric character and fails if it finds one.

If it reaches the end of the string, then the string is all numeric.

```
bool isInt(const std::string& in)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    if (!in.empty() && in[0] == '-')
        pos = 1;
    if (pos >= in.size())  // catch "" and "-"
        return false;
    do {
        if (!isdigit(in[pos]))
            return false;
    } while (++pos < in.length());

    return true;
}
```

This resolves your current problem but there is possible problem still: Is the string "123456789123456789" an int? It's too big to store in an int.